# How to do this star confetti

Tags: css, animation

I have a design where points would be displayed.Surrounding that I need to show stars which will start from the center of the points and move in all directions.Not sure how to start with this.[image]

Comment: Use stars svg for this design.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Find or make SVG image for the stars.
2. Use css `animation` and `transform` to make animation.

   1. Put the stars at the center.
   2. Rotate and move the stars.
   3. Adjust the speed and the positions.
3. Fire the animation on a specific trigger.

To achieve this, you might need to learn from many examples.